# Why is there a hard 60-day limit on migrating questions to other Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, migration

Suppose someone asks a question which would typically be migrated to another Stack Exchange site (say, Server Fault); it gets an answer, an upvote, and is basically forgotten about for a while. Then some user (possibly with higher reputation/more awareness) notices the fact that its on Stack Overflow. Why should it be impossible to migrate it?

Comment: 60 days is a *long time* in Stack Exchange terms. What would be the *point* in such cases, the OP has probably long forgotten about the post.

Comment: About it being a long time: If the question is forgotten, it could be 60 hours, 60 days or 60 weeks. About the point: The migration is intended for the general public, which will find the question (and the answer) on the appropriate website. Also, on the other SX site it might be a dupe of a question with better answers etc.

Comment: Other SE sites tend to not be thrilled about getting SO rejects.  Quality is almost always a problem.  So the time limit is a basic throttle, slowing down SO users that try to cleanup.  The odds that a question should be migrated after 3 months of review are *very* low.

Comment: The exact reasoning: [Disable migration for questions older than 60 days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151890). One of the major reasons: voting is screwed up. Majorly. Stack Overflow has a very different community, so voting between SO and, say, Server Fault doesn't translate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: How about migrating it with votes reset to 0?

Comment: @einpoklum: that already happens for posts with negative votes. In any case, older posts were asked in a different context, one now more than 2 months ago. If the question is also on-topic on the other site, *just ask a new question*; that's also a new post starting at score 0.